# Powershell Out-File: Force encoding to Ascii

Tags: powershell, character-encoding

I am attempting to normalize a set of TAB-delimited logfiles using Powershell.

Here is the current script:

```
(Get-ChildItem *.csv) |%{
#Store the name of the file & date
$Name = $_.basename
$FileDate = $_.CreationTime
#Prepends the following to each message: unique Identifer, Hostname, date
(Get-Content $_.fullname) -replace "^","AR-LOG|$Name|$FileDate|"|
#Replaces the TAB delimeter with a Pipe delimeter
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '   ','|'}  |
#Appends the resulting message in ascii
Out-File -append -FilePath normalized.log -Encoding ascii
```

A snippet of the input & output can be seen here:

http://pastebin.com/uaQadYUC

How can I force the output file to be ascii and not some type of unicode?

***Edit: Further troubleshooting reveals that the input files are actually windows-1252 encoded, which apparently Get-Content cannot handle natively(?)

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use the encoding flag on out-file as in `... | Out-File -encoding ascii myfile.txt`.  And if you're using `append`, make sure all appends use the same encoding or you'll end up with an unusable file.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing in the script (which you can see), but it does not appear to be working.

Comment: not work, if the string itself is utf8

Answer (score 4):

Change the format of a file from `ASCII` to `UTF8`:

`$filename = "c:\docs\demo.csv"
(Get-Content $filename) | Set-Content $filename -Encoding UTF8`

Answer (score 0):

Can you play around with ReadAllText method? It stores the whole file in a single string. Get-Content stores values as an array of strings where array value is the line of the file.

```
(Get-ChildItem *.csv) |%{
#Store the name of the file & date
$Name = $_.basename
$FileDate = $_.CreationTime
#Prepends the following to each message: unique Identifer, Hostname, date
([IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.fullname)) -replace "^","AR-LOG|$Name|$FileDate|"
#Replaces the TAB delimeter with a Pipe delimeter
-replace '   ','|'  |
#Appends the resulting message in ascii
Out-File -append -FilePath normalized.log -Encoding ascii
```